# load method in FileReference

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Can I implement the "load" method in FileReference in other way? My client use FP 9 and this method is implemented in FP 10. I am using BlazeDS + Spring and I want to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do file upload in FP 9 but the files have to go to the server.  The FileReference load method made it possible to "upload" to the client-side then allowing the developer to do something with the "file" before it gets sent to the server (if ever).  Here are some links that might help:
http://www.flex888.com/296/9-flex-file-upload-examples-visited.html
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001936.html

Comment: Thanks,
My intention was just to do(using FP9) something with the "file" before send it(using spring + blazeds) to the server. I was calling my "upload service" on "my select method" and my fileReference wasn't "complete loaded" to be uploaded. 
After reading some papers and blogs, I think that is impossible using FP9 by security reasons...
So, I will use the traditional form with FP9...flex + servlet or script.

-Oséas